# Please sign in to send a message

Tags: translation

How would I translate the phrase, "Please sign in to send the message".

I would think it's something like, "Qing 登录 fa xin" -- is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

请登录来送出信息 or 请登录来发送信息 or 请登录以便发送信息.

Comment: as a native speaker, I think the last one is the best.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean to say "To send the message, please first sign in", then “发送信息前请先登录” may sound more natural and clearer.